# Using a domain object to fetch data

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a domain object having id (auto generated), person_id, airport_id, name, position, status. person_id and airport_id combination can identify a row uniquely.

Is there a way to fill in these two properties and send the domain object through hibernate so that other fields will be populated by hibernate automatically. Another way to achieve this is by named query but that's my last option.

Please help.

Comment: You want to fetch the content (using 2 params) without using query?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using [HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html),  you could have leveraged the method [findByExample(Object)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#findByExample%28java.lang.Object%29).

Where, the param passed to the `findByExample` method would be the `criteria object` - so, in your case, an `entity` with `personId` and `airportId` set. The result of `findByExample(entity)`, is a `List` containing all the matching entities with other data filled.

If you are using plain hibernate, you can achieve this using [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html).

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(YourEntity.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("personId", p_id_value));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("airportId", a_id_value)); 
c.list(); //This should again return a list containing all the matching entities with the values filled
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this one using Criteria first.

Comment: OP should note that this approach is not doing what you ask for : "fill in 2 fields... and other fields will be populated".  The result will be another object instance, instead of Hibernate populating the missing properties to your Example object. (And the way you asked for is simply unreasonable in Hibernate.  You've better give up that idea)

Comment: If it does then you can accept this as an answer. Thanks in advance.